# Extract bold words in text with newline character

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell with text and newline symbols.

Example:

> pc laptop
> **Google - home**
> some words
> **android**
> some words

I need to extract bold text to another cell in the row.

```vb
Public Function findAllBold(ByVal rngText As Range) As String
    Dim theCell As Range
    Set theCell = rngText.Cells(1, 1)

    For i = 1 To Len(theCell.Value)       
        If theCell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = True Then          
            If theCell.Characters(i + 1, 1).Text = " " Then
                theChar = theCell.Characters(i, 1).Text & ", "
            Else
                theChar = theCell.Characters(i, 1).Text
            End If
            Results = Results & theChar
        End If
    Next i
    findAllBold = Results
End Function
```

My result is

> Google,  -,  homeandroid

Last words stuck together. I need them to be separated

Comment: Do you actually want to add these commas I. 'Google - Home' ?

Comment: Not required, i need just separate them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my two cents to your problem, assuming:

- Each line in your input is either bold or not;
- You'd like to find the entire line as single output in the concatenated result.

The function with optional delimiter (", " by default):

```
Function FindAllBold(rngText As Range, Optional Delimiter As String = ", ") As String

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Global = True: .Pattern = "^.+": .MultiLine = True
    For Each m In .Execute(rngText)
        If rngText.Characters(m.FirstIndex + 1, 1).Font.Bold = True Then
            If FindAllBold = "" Then
                FindAllBold = m
            Else
                FindAllBold = FindAllBold & Delimiter & m
            End If
        End If
    Next
End With
    
End Function
```

Call through, for example: `=FindAllBold(A1, CHAR(10))`

[image]

Comment: Fyi Though an old post to extract bold cell parts, you might be interested in my alternative post demonstrating an xml spreadsheet analyze using namespaces :+) @JvdV

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative via XML Spreadsheet analyze**

A quick alternative would be to use the XML spreadsheet content of each Range via  `.Value(11)` or `.Value(xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet)` to extract all **bold cell string parts**.

This will be executed by a simple `XPath`-search over all `<B>...</B>` *nodes* in the spreadsheet xml.

```
Function getBold(rng As Range)
'[0]Allow only 1 cell
    If rng.cells.Count <> 1 Then Exit Function
'[0]Get Value(11)
    Dim s As String
    s = rng.Value(xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet)   ' or: rng.Value(11)
'[1]Set xml document to memory
    Dim xDoc As Object: Set xDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
'[2]Add namespaces
    xDoc.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", _
    "xmlns:ss='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet' " & _
    "xmlns:ht='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'"
'[3]Get cells with Data/@Type "Number"
    If xDoc.LoadXML(s) Then            ' load wellformed string content
        Dim cell As Object, cells As Object
        Set cells = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//ht:B") ' XPath using namespace prefixes
        If cells.Length < 1 Then getBold = Array(): Exit Function
        Dim tmp(): ReDim tmp(0 To cells.Length - 1)
        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(tmp) To UBound(tmp)
            'Debug.Print "tmp(" & i & ") = " & cells(i).Text
            tmp(i) = cells(i).Text
        Next i
        '[4]return array
        getBold = tmp
    End If
End Function
```

[image: Extract bold cell parts]

- To extract the filltered cell parts you may call the above function e.g. via

```
    Sheet1.Range("B4").Value = Join(getBold(Tabelle1.Range("B2")), Chr(10))
```

- If you prefer a simple `Debug.Print`, voilà

```
    Debug.Print Join(getBold(Tabelle1.Range("B2")), Chr(10))
```

Comment: This is lovely.